# How do I stop this view from filling the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

My App is supposed to have the following layout (ie these 3 things stacked vertically):

```
Chart Name (String)
Tools (a pager with 3 tabs)
ChartGrid
```

The Chart Name is a set size, and then I want the Tools below that to use as much space as they need to, and then the ChartGrid should take up the rest of the space below that.

The overall layout is as follows (I've taken out the irrelevant bits):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChartName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_tools"
        android:name="com.path.appname.fragments.ToolsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewChartName"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tools" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_chartGrid"
        android:name="com.path.appname.fragments.ChartGridFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/au_adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_tools"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="5"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_chart_grid" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/au_adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_tools.xml is as follows:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart_tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolsWrapper"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and fragment_chartGrid is:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <com.path.appname.models.ChartGrid
        android:id="@+id/chartGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem I'm having is that the tools are taking up all the screen space, so I see the Chart Name and then the tools, and then nothing below that - just white space (if I add a background colour to the tools then I see the background colour). If I take out the tools, I can see the grid again.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: here's what I want (I've coloured the tools orange just to show which bit I mean; obviously I also need to sort out the numbers on the chart!):

[image: what I want to see]

And here's what I'm getting:

[image: what I'm getting]

Comment: Can you show required view, it will be more easy to understand by that.

Comment: show and example of your you get and an example of what you want

Comment: Is that necessary to use fragment as the tools and the chart view?. To my knowledge, `<fragment>` tag always try to fill the space so `layout_height="wrap_content"` cannot be applied. Or you can try to set a specific size for the fragment height instead of `wrap_content` to see if it works

Comment: I've added screenshots to show what I'm trying to achieve, and what I'm getting at the moment. I've coloured the tools bit orange to show which bit it is.

Comment: I don't need to make it a fragment, I guess, but I may need to reuse it at some point so it would be helpful if I could.

Comment: Change `match_parent` to `0dp` for widgets contained within a `ConstraintLayout` to see if that helps at all. `match_parent` is not recommended in `ConstraintLayout`. See the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints). Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

Comment: Thanks.  That didn't make any difference. I've set it to a fixed size instead, which seems to be working fine.  Thanks for the help!